# Android Lint Infrastructure error caused by Not all files in androidTestUtil configuration are APKs

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, lint, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am using android lint with after migrating to Kotlin DSL in gradle started getting this error

```
Execution failed for task ':base:lintDebug'.
> Lint infrastructure error
  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at com.android.tools.lint.gradle.api.ReflectiveLintRunner.runLint(ReflectiveLintRunner.kt:37)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.LintBaseTask.runLint(LintBaseTask.java:133)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.LintPerVariantTask.doTaskAction(LintPerVariantTask.java:52)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NonIncrementalGlobalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(BaseTask.kt:63)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Blocks.recordSpan(Blocks.java:51)

......

 Caused by: com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: Not all files in androidTestUtil configuration are APKs: /Users/me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.annotation/annotation/1.0.0/45599f2cd5965ac05a1488fa2a5c0cdd7c499ead/annotation-1.0.0.jar /Users/me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.test/monitor/1.3.0/60a29f8cfadc1a8e841d96dad42483d681130a9c/monitor-1.3.0.aar /Users/me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.test/rules/1.3.0/f7030a787ad72ccc283f24f3325336846fd521d5/rules-1.3.0.aar /Users/me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.test/runner/1.3.0/e8862a8d71f5a8ab90d822b7d9349c7e4e74e49b/runner-1.3.0.aar /Users/me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/junit/junit/4.12/2973d150c0dc1fefe998f834810d68f278ea58ec/junit-4.12.jar /Users/me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/42a25dc3219429f0e5d060061f71acb49bf010a0/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
```

I have following lintOptions

```
lintOptions {
        abortOnError !project.hasProperty("runBaseline")
        warningsAsErrors true
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        absolutePaths = false
        lintConfig file('../lint.xml') 
        if (!project.hasProperty("runBaseline")) {
            baseline file("lint-baseline.xml")
        } else if (project.name == "base"){
            lintConfig file('../lint-for-baseline.xml')
        }
        htmlOutput file("$project.buildDir/outputs/reports/lint.html")
        xmlOutput file("$project.buildDir/outputs/reports/lint-report.xml")
    }
```

They haven't changed. It is failing in CI and locally so I don't think it is related to my Android Studio locally (meaning invalidate cache doesn't help) but to the project itself.

Comment: BTW already tried abortOnError false, did nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to AGP 7.0 solved the failure. I still have this warning but it doesn't cause lint failures. you can track https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195342726

```
Not all files in androidTestUtil configuration are APKs: /Users/me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.annotation/annotation/1.0.0/45599f2cd5965ac05a1488fa2a5c0cdd7c499ead/annotation-1.0.0.jar /Users/me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.test/monitor/1.3.0/60a29f8cfadc1a8e841d96dad42483d681130a9c/monitor-1.3.0.aar /Users/me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.test/rules/1.3.0/f7030a787ad72ccc283f24f3325336846fd521d5/rules-1.3.0.aar /Users/me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.test/runner/1.3.0/e8862a8d71f5a8ab90d822b7d9349c7e4e74e49b/runner-1.3.0.aar /Users/me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/junit/junit/4.12/2973d150c0dc1fefe998f834810d68f278ea58ec/junit-4.12.jar /Users/me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/42a25dc3219429f0e5d060061f71acb49bf010a0/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
```